# Criação de elementos HTML com Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Galera, eu tenho a seguinte estrutura HTML:

```
<ul id="list_Viagens">
    <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="text">Viagem: <span class="destaque">201500124</span>  Filial de Origem: <span class="destaque">001 JUNDIAI</span></span>
            <span class="holder"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list_Notas">
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

E quero fazer-ló pelo Jquery usando o `append`.

Ai eu desenvolve o seguinte código Jquery:

```
elementViagem.append(
    $('<li>').addClass('has-sub')
             .append(
                 $('<a>').attr('href', '#')
                         .append(
                             $('<span>').addClass('text')
                                        .text('Viagem: ')
                                        .append(
                                            $('<span>').addClass('destaque')
                                                       .attr('data-element', 'viagem')
                                                       .text(val.numvia)
                                               )
                                         .text('Filial da Viagem: ')
                                         .append(
                                             $('<span>').addClass('destaque')
                                                        .attr('data-element', 'filori')
                                                        .text(val.filori)
                                               ),
                               $('<span>').addClass('holder')
                                  ),
                 $('<ul>').addClass('list_Notas')
    )
);
```

Mas, desta forma ele esta gerando o seguinte HTML:

```
<ul id="list_Viagens">
    <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="text">Filial da Viagem: <span class="destaque" data-element="filori">001</span></span>
            <span class="holder"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list_Notas"></ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Por que esta parte:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="text">Viagem: <span class="destaque">201500124</span>  Filial de Origem: <span class="destaque">001 JUNDIAI</span></span>
    <span class="holder"></span>
</a>
```

Não esta correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O uso da função [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) está sobrescrevendo todo o append que foi realizado anteriormente. Por isso apenas o append após a chamada ao `text()` é mantido.

Para evitar isso, continue utilizando [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) para colocar o texto livre que deseja e evitar que o conteúdo seja sobrescrito

```
elementViagem.append(
    $('<li>').addClass('has-sub')
             .append(
                 $('<a>').attr('href', '#')
                         .append(
                             $('<span>').addClass('text')
                                        .append('Viagem: ')
                                        .append(
                                            $('<span>').addClass('destaque')
                                                       .attr('data-element', 'viagem')
                                                       .text(val.numvia)
                                               )
                                         .append(' Filial da Viagem: ')
                                         .append(
                                             $('<span>').addClass('destaque')
                                                        .attr('data-element', 'filori')
                                                        .text(val.filori)
                                               ),
                               $('<span>').addClass('holder')
                                  ),
                 $('<ul>').addClass('list_Notas')
    )
);
```